# Run eclipse-mosquitto MQTT broker docker image and custom paho-mqtt Python clients inside minikube Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, containers, mqtt, cluster-computing

I want to run an MQTT broker and two clients inside a Kubernetes cluster and be able to send messages back and forth.

Therefore I wanted to use the [eclipse-mosquitto Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto/) and two custom clients that use the [paho-mqtt Python library](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/):

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

broker_address = "localhost"
port = 1883
client_id = "client1"
counter = 0

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(f"Client 1 received: {message.payload.decode()} - counter: {counter}")
    time.sleep(1)
    client.publish("test/topic", f"Client 1: {counter}")

client = mqtt.Client(client_id)
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker_address, port=port)
client.subscribe("test/topic")
client.loop_start()

while True:
    client.publish("test/topic", f"Client 1: {counter}")
```

This works perfectly fine in Docker when putting all of them on the same Docker network. The broker container is named `mosquitto-broker` which can then be found by the clients. They subscribe to a topic and publish messages on it.

However, recreating the same use-case on a Kubernetes cluster seems to require a different approach, since K8s has an own networking ecosystem and the `broker_address` will be different. Since my docker images `mqtt_client_1` and `mqtt_client_2` are local, I set the `imagePullPolicy` to `Never`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mqtt-deployment
  labels:
    app: mqtt
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mqtt
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mqtt
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eclipse-mosquitto
          image: eclipse-mosquitto
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1883
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mosquitto-config
              mountPath: /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
              subPath: mosquitto.conf
        - name: mqtt-client1
          image: mqtt_client_1
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          command:
            - python
            - /app/client1.py
        - name: mqtt-client2
          image: mqtt_client_2
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          command:
            - python
            - /app/client2.py
      volumes:
        - name: mosquitto-config
          configMap:
            name: mosquitto-config
```

I also use a configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-config
data:
  mosquitto.conf: |-
    listener 1883
    allow_anonymous true
```

However, the client pod exits with `Name or service not known` when trying to connect on the `broker_address` and `port`. How can I make client and server communicate via MQTT on the same network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include a kubernetes Service description that points to the Deployment.

The name of the service will then be the hostname you use in the client code to connect to the broker.

e.g.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtt-broker
spec:
  selector:
    app: mqtt
  ports:
    - name: mqtt-native
      targetPort: 1883
      port: 1883
```

You would use `mqtt-broker` as the hostname (or `mqtt-broker.<namespace>` for cross namespace accesss)